# cardinal of the union of an increasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $A_n\subset \mathbb{R}$ for all $n$. If $\vert A_n\vert=C$ for all $n$ where $C$ is the cardinality of the real numbers and $A_n\subset A_{n+1}$. then Is it true that

$\vert \bigcup_n A_n\vert=C$?

I appreciate any reference or suggestion .

Comment: Note that if we take the *intersection* of a *decreasing*  sequence, instead, then we can get any cardinality $\le C$; this is a good exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty A_n\subseteq\Bbb R\implies |\bigcup_n A_n|\le C,$$
but
$$A_1\subseteq\bigcup_nA_n\implies |\bigcup_nA_n|\ge C.$$

Comment: if  $A_n\subset  \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ the same is true?